# Why angular is not recognizing if a user is logged in with keycloak?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-sign-on, keycloak

So I'm trying to set up a sso system with keycloak on my angular app.

I have downloaded the keycloak library keycloak-angular@4.0.2, setted up a keycloak server at localhost:8080/auth, added the keycloak.json on the root of the app, that keycloak made for me:

```
   {
  "realm": "my-app",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "my-app",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
  }
```

Also I added the keycloak initi function in the main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
//....some other import....
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';


var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([KeycloakService]);
var keycloak = injector.get(KeycloakService)

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}



keycloak.init()
    .then(() => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule))
    .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
```

Now, if I try to make a registration page, something like this:

```
export class registration implements OnInit {

  constructor(keycloak:KeycloakService) {

    keycloak.register();

   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

It works and sends me to a registration page and if I create an account it appears in the keycloak server.
BUT... even if I am not logged in with any account it lets me access any page, also, if I try:

```
keycloak.isLoggedIn().then(() => console.log("logged"), ()=>console.log("Not logged"));
```

The result is "logged", but if I try:

```
keycloak.loadUserProfile();
```

Then it says

```
The user profile was not loaded as the user is not logged in.
```

I can't understand how it works, am I missing something?
So my question is:
- How do I prevent pages to show if I am not logged in?
- How do I make a user log and stay logged and angular to recognize who is logged and who is not.

UPDATE: As asked I'm adding app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { KeycloakService, KeycloakAngularModule } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { initializer } from './utils/app-init';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AuthenticationModule } from './core/auth/authentication.module';
import { NgxPermissionsModule } from 'ngx-permissions';

import { LayoutModule } from './content/layout/layout.module';
import { PartialsModule } from './content/partials/partials.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AclService } from './core/services/acl.service';
import { LayoutConfigService } from './core/services/layout-config.service';
import { MenuConfigService } from './core/services/menu-config.service';
import { PageConfigService } from './core/services/page-config.service';
import { UserService } from './core/services/user.service';
import { UtilsService } from './core/services/utils.service';
import { ClassInitService } from './core/services/class-init.service';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { GestureConfig, MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

import { MessengerService } from './core/services/messenger.service';
import { ClipboardService } from './core/services/clipboard.sevice';

import { PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { LayoutConfigStorageService } from './core/services/layout-config-storage.service';
import { LogsService } from './core/services/logs.service';
import { QuickSearchService } from './core/services/quick-search.service';
import { SubheaderService } from './core/services/layout/subheader.service';
import { HeaderService } from './core/services/layout/header.service';
import { MenuHorizontalService } from './core/services/layout/menu-horizontal.service';
import { MenuAsideService } from './core/services/layout/menu-aside.service';
import { LayoutRefService } from './core/services/layout/layout-ref.service';
import { SplashScreenService } from './core/services/splash-screen.service';
import { DataTableService } from './core/services/datatable.service';


import 'hammerjs';
import { AppAuthGuardComponent } from './utils/keycloak/app-auth-guard/app-auth-guard.component';
import { KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PROVIDER } from './utils/keycloak/keycloak.http';

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
    // suppressScrollX: true
};

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, AppAuthGuardComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        LayoutModule,
        PartialsModule,
        CoreModule,
        OverlayModule,
        AuthenticationModule,
        NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        KeycloakAngularModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        AclService,
        LayoutConfigService,
        LayoutConfigStorageService,
        LayoutRefService,
        MenuConfigService,
        PageConfigService,
        UserService,
        UtilsService,
        ClassInitService,
        MessengerService,
        ClipboardService,
        LogsService,
        QuickSearchService,
        DataTableService,
        SplashScreenService,
        KeycloakService,
        KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PROVIDER,
        {
            provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
            useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
        },
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializer,
            multi: true,
            deps: [KeycloakService]
        },


        // template services
        SubheaderService,
        HeaderService,
        MenuHorizontalService,
        MenuAsideService,
        {
            provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
            useClass: GestureConfig
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Did you implement `APP_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: Yes i did implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Check and add `loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,` to the init config,

mine was like below, and It has resolved the issue for me,

```
export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise {
  return (): Promise => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await keycloak.init({
          config: {
            url: environment.keycloak.issuer,
            realm: environment.keycloak.realm,
            clientId: environment.keycloak.clientId
          },
          loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'check-sso',
            checkLoginIframe: true
          },
          bearerExcludedUrls: []
        });
        resolve(1);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

constructor(protected keycloakService: KeycloakService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.keycloakService.isLoggedIn().then(
    () => {
      console.log('logged');
      this.keycloakService.loadUserProfile().then(
        () => console.log(this.keycloakService.getUsername()),
        () => console.log('Failed to load user profile');
      );
    },
    () => console.log('Not logged');
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).